# In a gen_server behaviour, how to implement broadcast news between nodes with function nodes()?

Tags: erlang

I know how to send message, but receive function is troubling me.

```
broadcast(Message) ->
    Nodes  = nodes(),
    gen_server:cast(aname, {broadcast, Message, Nodes}).

handle_cast({broadcast, Message, Nodes}, State) ->
    lists:map(fun(x) -> {aname, X} ! Message end, Nodes).
```

How should I receive the message from other nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gen_server:cast/3 or gen_server:multi_call/3

Answer (score 2):

Messages sent to a gen_server process using the `!` operator are received in the `handle_info` function:

```
handle_info(Message, State) ->
    %% do something with Message here
    {noreply, State}.
```

This happens independently of whether the message was sent from another node.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cast to many registered gen_server:s on different nodes use gen_server:abcast/2 or gen_server:abcast/3 if you want to address some of them. As for receiving, there is no observable difference if you get messages from the local or remote node if yo do not include anything in the message that can be used to determine the sender.

Comment: If I broadcast a message like this {message, node(), Content}, can other nodes receive this format?

Comment: Emm...receiver is a loop while sender is not, how should i deal with this so that i can send or receive anytime.